# Keras model.fit and model.test_on_batch return different val_loss (by orders of magnitude)

Tags: python, keras

I have a discrepancy between the val_loss's produced by `model.fit` and `model.test_on_batch`.

For `model.fit`, after 1 epoch of batch size 4 and 50k training set size, this is the output

```
50000/50000 [==============================] - 508s 10ms/step - loss: 1.5587 - acc: 0.9442 - val_loss: 0.6883 - val_acc: 0.9721
```

Notice that `val_loss = 0.6883`.

I then stopped the training, and trained the model with `model.train_on_batch`, validating every 1k batches. I did not reset the model, so the weights are not changed. After 1k batches, I get this output:

```
Batch 1139: Train[0.539348,0.977112] ; Val[146.972092,0.972529] ; Duration=0.040436 s
```

Notice that here the validation loss is `146.97...`. How is that possible? Does `model.fit` do some post-processing to the validation loss?

---

## `model.fit` code

```
batch_size = 4
epochs = 300

myhist = model.fit(x_test,y_test,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,shuffle=True,validation_data=(val_x[:1000,],val_y[:1000,]),callbacks=[plot_losses])
```

---

## `model.train_on_batch` iteration

```
n_batches = 500000
batch_size = 4
val_size = 1000
val_freq = 1000

val_loss,val_acc = 0,0

model_check = '17102019_1.hd5'
val_loss_min = 1000000


for ib in range(n_batches):
    batch_init = time.time()
    batch_x,batch_y = generate_mini_batch(batch_size,x_test,y_test,linear_comb=False,trans=False)
    train_loss,train_acc = model.train_on_batch(batch_x,batch_y)
    batch_end = time.time()-batch_init
    clear_output(wait=True)
    if (ib % val_freq == 0) & (ib > 0):        
        val_loss,val_acc = model.test_on_batch(val_x[:val_size,],val_y[:val_size,])
        if val_loss < val_loss_min:
            model.save(model_check)
            val_loss_min = val_loss
 
    
    
    print('Batch %i: Train[%f,%f] ; Val[%f,%f] ; Duration=%f s'%(ib,train_loss,train_acc,val_loss,val_acc,batch_end))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `model.test_on_batch` returns the sum of losses of the batch entries, while `model.train_on_batch` returns the average loss, so that solves the issue.